# How to read files present in array nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, fs

I would like to know to read the files and search for keyword `sample` in nodejs.

If keyword found, display the path

```
const allfiles = [
  'C:\\Users\\public',
  'C:\\Users\\public\\images',
  'C:\\Users\\public\\javascripts\\index1.js',
  'C:\\Users\\public\\javascripts\\index2.js'
]


const readFile = (path, opts = 'utf8') =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   try{
      let result=[];
      fs.readFile(path, opts, (err, data) => {
        if (err) reject(err)
        else {
          if(data.indexOf("sample")>=0){
             result.push(data);
             resolve(result);
          }
        }
      })
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.log("e", e);
     }
  })

  const run = async () => {
    allfiles.forEach(e=>{
      const s = await readFile(e);
      console.log(s);
    })
  }
run();

Expected Output
[
  'C:\\Users\\public\\javascripts\\index1.js',
  'C:\\Users\\public\\javascripts\\index2.js'
]
```

Comment: What is the actual output you get?

Comment: Does the order of the results matter? Do you have an inclination as to where the keyword will mostly likely be in the file? How big are the files?

Comment: @James thanks for reply, there is no order of results, no inclination of keyword, small file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tips:

1. What happens when `"sample"` isn't found in `readFile`?
2. You're currently pushing the `data` into `result` instead of the `path`.
3. Think about what you're trying to accomplish with `readFile`. To me, what you want to do is see if that file has the word `"sample"`, and return `true` if so and if not return `false`. So I'd name the function `checkIfFileHasSample` and have it return a boolean. Then in your `run` function, in the `forEach` you have the `path`, so that is where I'd add the path to a list of results.
4. Maybe you already realized this, but `run` is never actually *called* in your code sample. Ie. `run()` doesn't happen.

Solution:

You had some syntax errors and a [tricky gotcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop) with async-await with `run`. For the syntax errors, it'll come with experience, but I'd also recommend using ESLint to help you catch them, as well as making sure your code is always properly indented.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const allfiles = [
  "C:\\Users\\public",
  "C:\\Users\\public\\images",
  "C:\\Users\\public\\javascripts\\index1.js",
  "C:\\Users\\public\\javascripts\\index2.js",
];

const checkIfFileHasSample = (path, opts = "utf8") =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(path, opts, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        if (data.includes("sample")) {
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          resolve(false);
        }
      }
    });
  });

const run = async () => {
  const results = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
    try {
      const file = allFiles[i];
      const hasSample = await checkIfFileHasSample(file);

      if (hasSample) {
        results.push(file);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  console.log(results);
};
run();
```

Comment: thanks a lot for helping, but getting error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: EISDIR:
illegal operation on a directory, `

Comment: Whoops, I forgot the `try-catch`. I updated my code to include it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#promise_rejection for why it's needed. That won't solve your root problem though. `illegal operation on a directory` sounds like there's a problem with `fs.readFile`. It worked for me, so it's probably that your file paths are wrong.